# CameraWithTensor shows black screen In expo react native

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, machine-learning, expo, webgl

I am making an object detection app using coco Ssd followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kSLY59X5iaA

I ran into a versioning Issue. The tfjs has issues with webgl thus leading to a black screen in the app.

I have mentioned the github issue thread but it doesn't solve the problem.

This is one of the warnings in the console.

```
tf.nonMaxSuppression() in webgl locks the UI thread. Call tf.nonMaxSuppressionAsync() instead
```

But this too leads to the same github thread mentioned at the bottom of the question.

This is my app.js code

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { cameraWithTensors } from "@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native";
import { Camera } from "expo-camera";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import {
    Dimensions,
    LogBox,
    Platform,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
} from "react-native";
const TensorCamera = cameraWithTensors(Camera);
import * as cocoSSd from "@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd";
import * as tf from "@tensorflow/tfjs";
import Canvas from "react-native-canvas";

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");
LogBox.ignoreAllLogs(true);
export default function App() {
    
    const [model, setModel] = useState();
    let context = useRef();
    let canvas = useRef();

    let textureDim =
        Platform.OS === "ios"
            ? { width: 1920, height: 1080 }
            : { width: 1200, height: 1600 };

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const { status } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
              await tf.ready();
              tf.env().set('WEBGL_PACK_DEPTHWISECONV', false);
            setModel(await cocoSSd.load());
        })();
    }, []);

    function handleCameraStream(images) {
        const loop = async () => {
            const nextImageTensor = images.next().value;
            if (!model || !nextImageTensor)
                throw new Error("Model or image not loaded");
            model
                .detect(nextImageTensor)
                .then((predictions) => {
                    drawRectangle(predictions, nextImageTensor);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
            requestAnimationFrame(loop);
        };
        loop();
    }

    function drawRectangle(predictions, nextImageTensor) {
        if (!context.current || !canvas.current) return;
        const scaleWidth = width / nextImageTensor.shape[1];
        const scaleHeight = height / nextImageTensor.shape[0];

        const flipHorizontal = Platform.OS === "ios" ? false : true;

        context.current.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);

        for (const prediction of predictions) {
            const [x, y, width, height] = prediction.bbox;

            const boundingBoxX = flipHorizontal
                ? canvas.current.width - x * scaleWidth - width * scaleWidth
                : x * scaleWidth;
            const boundingBoxY = y * scaleHeight;

            context.current.strokeRect(
                boundingBoxX,
                boundingBoxY,
                width * scaleWidth,
                height * scaleHeight
            );

            context.current.strokeText(
                prediction.class,
                boundingBoxX - 5,
                boundingBoxY - 5
            );
        }
    }

    async function handleCanvas(can) {
        if (can) {
            can.width = width;
            can.height = height;
            const ctx = can.getContext("2d");
            ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
            ctx.lineWidth = 2;
            ctx.fillStyle = "red";

            context.current = ctx;
            canvas.current = can;
        }
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <TensorCamera
                style={styles.camera}
                type={Camera.Constants.Type.back}
                cameraTextureHeight={textureDim.height}
                cameraTextureWidth={textureDim.width}
                resizeHeight={200}
                resizeWidth={152}
                resizeDepth={3}
                onReady={handleCameraStream}
                autorender={true}
                useCustomShadersToResize={false}
            />
            <Canvas style={styles.canvas} ref={handleCanvas} />
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
    },
    camera: {
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
    },
    canvas: {
        position: "absolute",
        zIndex: 100000000,
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
    },
});
```

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "detectiontest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.15.0",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.1",
    "@tensorflow-models/coco-ssd": "^2.2.2",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^2.3.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native": "^0.3.0",
    "@types/react-native-canvas": "^0.1.8",
    "expo": "~42.0.5",
    "expo-camera": "~11.2.2",
    "expo-gl": "~10.4.2",
    "expo-gl-cpp": "~10.4.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.4",
    "react-native-canvas": "^0.1.38",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.19.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "react-native-webview": "11.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Things that I have tried:
tried downgrading all the dependencies like suggested in :  https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/6230#issuecomment-1091015255

Answer (score 0):

It works for me! You may have a module compliancy issue...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33057660)