# How to embed a website in expo React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, camera, expo

I want to embed or just redirect to a website I made which uses a webcam. I can redirect to the website with `webView` however the camera doesn't work.

This is the website I want to embed. https://chinmaymhatre.github.io/currency_detector

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can permit camera access inside a webview in a react native or expo app because of security concerns, neither could I find anything like that.

I think it would be easier to just implement this right into the react native app(if the app you want to show in the webview is written in javascript)

Comment: The website shows a machine learning model. I have been trying to implement the Tensorflow camera into the expo app But it doesn't work. I have put a question in stack overflow if you would like to take a look at it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71900216/camerawithtensor-shows-black-screen-in-expo-react-native

Comment: Instead of embedding the website is it possible to redirect to a browser and show the app?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried something similar. So, sometime ago I was making a video streaming app using **React Native** for a website that I made using **WebRTC** which was using camera and other medias(Video, Audio and Screen). I tried to be smart and tried to embed the webpage directly into the React Native App. My Idea was that I could access the Camera and other user media in Mobile Browser So, it should work with React Native as well. But this is not how the react-native works, **React Native doesn't uses iframe** to work or in other words react-native develops **Native Apps** for both IOS and Android. You can always implement an iframe in expo, but this is against the Device Security to provide such level of access to user-media. The device doesn't allow such functionality via iframe [(here's the link to a live example how to implement iframe in expo)](https://snack.expo.dev/h9hM6LUMX). So, to understand it better You should use **react-native-cli** to make a simple app not expo. Now for using camera in expo there's a package called **[expo-camera (here's link)](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/)** Which helps you develop camera oriented apps using Expo. If this doesn't answer your questions then let me know. Happy Coding :)

Comment: The website shows a machine learning model. I have been trying to implement the Tensorflow camera into the expo app But it doesn't work. I have put a question in stack overflow if you would like to take a look at it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71900216/camerawithtensor-shows-black-screen-in-expo-react-native